# After executing laravel project on localhost php page shows error url not found

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

after deployment on localhost project index.php shows[trying to load home page but it shows url not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwu6i.jpg)

Tried solution
Updated port number from apache httpd.conf 80 to 81

Comment: what do you mean by clicking on `web.php`? that is a route file, you don't run them .... the entry point of your application is the `index.php` file in the `public` folder

Comment: Is there any error message you could share? Neither any entry in the PHPUnit configuration nor any in the Apache configuration might be relevant

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the .env file to see what is your APP_URL